# What is this pipe in my garage for?

Tags: pipe, garage, pvc

[image]

[image]

I measured it and it would come out under the cement where I approximately marked in red in the next picture. The main house sits on the other side of that cement walkway.

[image]

My only guess is it has something to do with central vac that the house used to have but was ripped out for some reason (evidence in the basement). But why fill it in?

Comment: My first two thoughts are water drainage (but why the pipe?) and conduit for power, air hose, or whatever. Have you tried fishing something through it or doing sound location testing? Have someone tap on it and listen outside. It might turn and go out to the yard.

Comment: It's filled with something solid so nothing can be fished through it. Could not hear anything anywhere as the ground and cement isolate sound pretty well.

Comment: That's a knockout/test cap (for temporary debris protection). Is it also filled?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Is what also filled? The pictures are of the same pipe.

Comment: that path is too high, which is why your wall's rotting

Comment: You said the pipe is filled. I'm asking how you know that when there's a plastic cap over it. What's filling the pipe?

Comment: @isherwood It is not a cap, the pipe is filled with something that is hard but faintly squishy to touch.

Comment: @Jasen Why would the walkway being high cause a wall to rot?

Comment: water coming over the foundation of the wall instead of draining away

Comment: I think you're mistaken. I can plainly see the flange on the end of the pipe and the translucent plastic. Can you see something I can't?

Comment: @Jasen This walkway is raised about 1 ft higher than the ground. It is also covered with a roof completely. I have never seen a drop of water here. I also see no rotting wall?

Comment: that wood strip shows signs of damp, water doesn't only come from above.

Comment: @Jasen The one on the bottom? There is a small gap and it is filled with pollen and debris in the photo. Stack made me downsize the quality of the photo to upload.

Comment: No, in the first photo. The bottom wall plate has been wet.

Comment: The way the concrete hole is shaped (clean edges) indicates it was installed when the house was built.  From it's size, I would guess it was for running a car inside the garage.   You would route a hose to carry the exhaust fumes out the pipe.  Are there any other signs a previous owner was a 'car guy'?

Answer (score 1):

Radon vent? Pop the cap off of it and see if it turns and goes under the slab.

Comment: Looks like a layer of caulking inside the pipe. Bad way to cap a pipe. Curious to know if the pipe slopes to the house. Perhaps once that plug is out, pour some water in, that is if the basement is not finished of course.

Comment: I have a radon system installed, it is definitely not part of that system.

Comment: The "cap" looks to me like a polyethylene plug or some such.  It's plausible that it could be part of a radon system, or a pipe installed just in case a radon system was later needed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they put in pipe for future add on . For electric or some thing other to get beyond slab.

Comment: Agreed. Could have been for the now abandoned central vacuum system, and if so, you would want it plugged against pest entry.